# How to retrieve Powershell property / objects

Tags: azure, powershell

I ran the following Azure command in PowerShell to fetch the keyvault certificate:

```
Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName "ssl-keyvault-appservice" -Name "PI"
```

I got the output

[image]

Since I'm new to PowerShell, I'm not sure how to retrieve the thumbprint alone. I searched for Azure PowerShell command for thumbprint alone, but I can't find anything.

Is there any way in PowerShell to get only the thumbprint property alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run the following -

```
(Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName "ssl-keyvault-appservice" -Name "PI").Thumbprint
```

**OR**

```
Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName "ssl-keyvault-appservice" -Name "PI" | Select -property Thumbprint
```